# How to Ingest SAP ODP OData services with a Delta approach via Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are trying to consume SAP ODP OData services (See [Using the OData Service for Extracting ODP Data](https://help.sap.com/viewer/ccc9cdbdc6cd4eceaf1e5485b1bf8f4b/7.5.9/en-US/50f4ee6253134d3cafa25b9444f0c5a9.html)), and due to large volumes we would like to use their Delta Token approach (i.e. CDC) so that we only need to get changes after the initial load. This seems like a common use case to me but I cannot find any Azure Data Factory (ADF) documentation that addresses this.
What ADF Connector should we use?

ADF OData Connector does not appear to allow HTTP Request Headers to be sent, so we can't pass Prefer: odata.track-changes.